# Getting remote debugging monitor not available error in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I am just trying to run an application locally. I got the source code from source control and when I try to debug it, VS gives an error saying MSVSMON.exedoes not appear to be running on the remote machine.
Not sure why I am getting this error when I want to debug locally.
It is a windows application that I am trying to run.

PS: The same application on another machine seems to be working i.e. a friend is able to debug whereas I can just run it not debug

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem recently and it drove me nuts for a while; and there are a lot of results if you Google it - none of which helped me. In my case if I changed the build target to 32 bit  instead off 64 it solved the problem for me.

No idea what the root cause of the problem is though.